# Local Notification: setWhen()

Tags: c#, time, xamarin

I'm developing a mobile application using Xamarin (Android), and it has a notification feature. I was able to create the notification using Local Notification for Xamarin. My problem is I want my notification to view at 7:00 am. My problem is what should be the value of my .setWhen(?) to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Please post sample code you have tried.

Comment: `setWhen` is only a timestamp for the notification; it doesn't govern the time that it gets displayed, it governs the time you see on the top-right of the notification. You can't schedule notifications for the future directly from the notification API. You [need to use the alarm manager](https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223) to schedule it for the future.

Comment: Does alarm manager will work even if I totally close(destroy or kill) the application?